# How do I access the 'friend node' using the Facebook Graph API?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm trying to use the Facebook Graph API to return some of my friends facebook posts, and it seems like I need a 'friend node' or something to access that. I currently have a user node that will return the facebook posts that I myself have posted, but I want to be able to return my feed of posts from my friends using the Graph API instead of returning my own posts. How can I do this? What permissions would I need to have in order for this to be possible? Thanks!